# Announcing proposed SE site for Southeast Asian languages

Tags: discussion

In the past there have been a few proposals for some of the languages of Southeast Asia on Stack Exchanges "Area 51", but none have made it to the beta stage. I'm not sure if any have made it to the commitment stage.

In the hopes that united numbers of people interested in all the languages of the area might be enough where it has turned out that the numbers interested in particular languages have not been, I have proposed a new SE site for all SE Asian languages:

> [**Southeast Asian languages**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/78889/southeast-asian-languages?referrer=RjU5vZ97dH8Aw7hjn5MhOA2)
>   Proposed Q&A site for language enthusiasts, learners, linguists, polyglots, and travelers interested in Burmese (Myanmar), Indonesian, Khmer (Cambodian), Lao (Laotian), Malay, Tagalog (Filipino), Thai, Vietnamese, minority languages of the region, and their scripts.

In case you haven't noticed it already and you are interested in any of these languages it would be great if you want to follow the proposal.

It's intended to be for all types of questions, not just linguistic ones, similar to the sites we already have for [Chinese](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6388/chinese-language), [Engl](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1269/english-language-usage)[ish](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners), [French](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29480/french-language), [German](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18413/german-language), [Italian](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42949/italian-language), [Japanese](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7526/japanese-language), [Russian](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10848/russian-language), and [Spanish](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language).

(By the way, there is also a [**Khmer Language** proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/76781/khmer-language).)

Comment: I'm interested in the Austronesian languages in this area, but know little to nothing about the others. How do I follow it? And should I?

Comment: Just click on the link to the proposal on Area51 and it should ask you if you want to follow it. If it doesn't then just click on the follow button. It covers the Austronesian languages. Just like Stack Overflow you don't have to be interested in every topic the site covers.  Shouldn't you follow it? What bad could happen? (-: